# Netlogo programming: How to code a "repulsive" motion?

Tags: math, computer-science, netlogo

I am running out of fuel thinking how to code a "repulsive" motion in netlogo. 
Here it is: We are trying to set up a model in which sheepdog herd a group of sheep. When the dog is close to the sheep (that is when the distance smaller than the "response distance" of the sheep) the sheep will run away from the dog. I don't know how to do this "sheep run away from dog when their distance is smaller than the response distance". 
Can somebody helps me with that? 
Thanks very much!!

Comment: What are you having trouble figuring out? Can you calculate the sheep-dog distance? Can you find the desired sheep direction?

Comment: @TimN I am having trouble figuring out the relationship between the dog and the nearest sheep and their panic distances. When the dog go near the nearest sheep and distance drop below the panic distance, the sheep will go to the opposite way as the dog does. How to code that? Assume we have such terms as "panic_distance" etc.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a complete solution. Explanations follow.

```
breed [sheep a-sheep]
breed [dogs dog]

globals [
  panic-distance
  the-dog
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set panic-distance 10
  set-default-shape sheep "sheep"
  create-sheep 50 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  create-dogs 1 [
    set the-dog self
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask the-dog [
    rt random 30
    lt random 30
    fd 1
  ]
  ask sheep [
    if distance the-dog < panic-distance [
      face the-dog
      right 180
      fd 1
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

There are two key statements in your comments, and they translate pretty straightforwardly to NetLogo code:

> When the dog go near the nearest sheep and distance drop below the panic distance

The "nearest sheep" is probably a bit of red herring in terms of how to approach it. What you probably want to do is to ask each sheep if the current distance to the dog is lesser than the panic distance. NetLogo has the [`distance`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#distance) primitive just for that! In code, it becomes:

`ask sheep [if distance the-dog < panic-distance [...]]`

You just need to replace the `...` with what you want to sheep to do in that case, which is described by your next statement:

> the sheep will go to the opposite way as the dog does

I guess by that, you probably meant *away* from the dog, because "the opposite way as the dog does" could be actually be *towards* the dog.

NetLogo **doesn't** have a `face-away-from` primitive, but it has a [`face`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#face) primitive, which will have the sheep turn towards the dog. You can use that, and then turn it all the way back so it can run away:

```
face the-dog
right 180
```

And there you go. That's the core of it. You can play with the rest as you please.

Answer (score 0):

Open NetLogo and take a look on the *Shepherds* demo of the *Model Library* (find it in the *File* menu).

You can also find it [online here](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/Shepherds).

Comment: Thanks for you info though. I don't think that we are talking about the same thing.